# Quantum state carried by a photon

Tags: photons, quantum-information

How is a quantum state of a photon transferred into an excitation in a matter system?

Kindly suggest me papers which deal with the math required for this.

Comment: What do you mean by "quantum state *carried* by a photon"?

Comment: A photon is the transfer of energy, momentum and angular momentum from an electromagnetic field to an electric charge in matter. It's the same process as all classical field-charge interactions, except that this one is quantized. It is not clear what you are asking. These are simply definitions of electromagnetism that are based on observations.

Comment: If you want to see the Lagrangian of quantum electrodynamics, that's here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics, but you really need to read an entire book on quantum field theory to get an idea of the non-trivial problems that stem from this formulation.